# React Native variable getting undefined before running method

Tags: react-native

I have a function that calls a method that is in my Helper.js file.

```
import { getTest } from '../../common/Helper';
...

myMethod() {
   ...
   const test = getTest(this.state.myID);
   console.log(test);
}
...
```

My Helper.js:

```
export const getTest = (pID) => {
  axios.get('http://myserver.com/', {
    params: {
      method: 'getVacantUnits',
      propertyID: pID
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  }).catch((error) => {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
    return 0;
  });
};
```

It is odd because my output is:

```
undefined
myDataContent
```

It looks like that "const test" is receiving undefined before the getTest being run. Why is it happening?

Thanks

Comment: You're not returning the get request.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please give me an example? I'm returning: return response.data

Comment: You're not returning the Promise that `axios.get` returns, and you're not `await`ing it in the other function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new with react native. How can I return the Promise?

Comment: Change: `axios.get('http://myserver.com/'...` to :`return axios.get('http://myserver.com/'...`

Answer (score -1):

It's returning this first since it's not awaiting the result:

```
console.log(test);
```

2 easy ways to fix this I am showing below, first with promise:

```
 const test = getTest(this.state.myID).then(response=> console.log(response)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Add in return as well since you need to return from outermost function

```
export const getTest = (pID) => {
              return axios.get('http://myserver.com/', {
                params: {
                  method: 'getVacantUnits',
                  propertyID: pID
                }
              }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
              }).catch((error) => {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
                return 0;
              });
            };
```

second using async await:

```
// add in await
    export const getTest = async (pID) => {
      return axios.get('http://myserver.com/', {
        params: {
          method: 'getVacantUnits',
          propertyID: pID
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
      }).catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
        return 0;
      });
    };

     // here you are awaiting the response before you run console.log
     const test = await getTest(this.state.myID);
     console.log(test);
```

You can solve this in several other ways, but I think these are the 2 easiest.  Basically think about the fact that those are run synchronously and the console.log executes before the function returns, so if you "wait" then it makes it so the console.log() is dependent on the first function executing first.

Comment: Using the first option: "Undefined is not an object (evaluating '(0, _Helper. getTest(this.state.myID).then')... Using the second option, it says 'await is a reserved word' when I try to put it in getTest = await (pID)

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 you can only `await` in an `async` function.

Comment: @stephen the function doesn't return anything. There's nothing to `.then` or `await`.

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes everyone- I forgot to add the return here:  `RETURN axios.get('http://myserver.com/', {`   will update my answer